# Spring MVC. HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I began to learn "Spring MVC" from this course: http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro
At step "Building->Run the Application" I'm stuck.

When I try to go to link `http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html`
I get "HTTP Status 404"

```
HTTP Status 404 - /FitnessTracker/WEB-INF/jsp/Hello.jsp
type Status report
message /FitnessTracker/WEB-INF/jsp/Hello.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight.controller"></context:component-scan>

  <!--
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
  -->

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.pluralsight.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello WorldX");
        return "Hello"; 
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

`http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/` - it's work (file: webapp/index.jsp)

Comment: Have you tried with the commented version of the `InternalResourceViewResolver`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message says that it's looking for `Hello.jsp`. And indeed, your controller returns the following view name: `"Hello"`. But your screenshot shows that your file is naled `hello.jsp`. The case matters.

Answer (score 4):

Try returning the properly cased view name which matches the JSP `hello.jsp` from the controller.  Currently the controller returns `Hello` while the JSP is named `hello.jsp`, causing the 404.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello WorldX");
        //return "Hello"; 
        return "hello"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your web.xml the  to

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hit http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/ , it search for index.jsp file and return it. But when you hit http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting it will search for file named "Hello.jp" because you are returning Hello in the controller method. But the file name is "hello.jsp". Note that it is case sensitive. So that was your mistake. You have to retun hello rather than Hello. It should work fine after that.

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
public String sayHello (Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello WorldX");
    //return "Hello"; 
    return "hello"; 
}
}
```